# $f(x) = x^3-x^2+3x-1$ and $f(1) = 2$, find $g'(2)$ if $g(x) = f^{-1} (x)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

$f(x) = x^3-x^2+3x-1$ and $f(1) = 2$, find $g'(2)$ if $g(x) = f^{-1} (x)$. 
I'm stuck.

Can I get hints only? No anwser please.

Comment: I can't understand why it is given $\;f(1)=2\;$ after we're given the function. Perhaps this is something else?

Answer (score 2):

You can use this formula:

$$\frac{d}{dx}{f^{-1}(x)}=\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(x))}$$

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

- To find $f(1)$, plug $1$ into $f(x) = x^3-x^2+3x-1$.
- To find $g'(2)$ Notice that by the chain rule $$(f(g(x)))' = 1 \Rightarrow f'(g(x))g'(x) = 1 \Rightarrow g'(x) = \frac{1}{f'(g(x))}$$

Answer (score 0):

hint: compute $f^\prime(1)$  and then use the fact that the slopes of $f$  at $1$ and of $g$ at the corresponding point $2$ are reciprocals.